# find index of the object an array angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

for example I have this array :

```
  $scope.records = [
    {
      "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "Country" : "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "Country" : "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "Country" : "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
      "Country" : "Austria"
    }
  ];
```

How to get value index from object? with example "Country" : "Austria" this index is 3

Comment: this should have been an easy web search

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) in the latest browsers, but there's no support for this in Internet Explorer, only Edge

```js
let $scope = {};

$scope.records = [
    {
      "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "Country" : "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "Country" : "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "Country" : "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
      "Country" : "Austria"
    }
];

let index = $scope.records.findIndex( record => record.Country === "Austria" );

console.log(index); // 3
```

For support in IE9 and up, you could use `Array.some` instead

```js
var $scope = {};

$scope.records = [{
  "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
  "Country": "Germany"
}, {
  "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
  "Country": "Sweden"
}, {
  "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
  "Country": "Mexico"
}, {
  "Name": "Ernst Handel",
  "Country": "Austria"
}];

var index = -1;

$scope.records.some(function(obj, i) {
  return obj.Country === "Austria" ? index = i : false;
});

console.log(index);
```

Comment: You could modify it slightly to use [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). At least then it would stop iterating once you have found your index, same browser support too.

Comment: @ste2425 - I could, I could even add a ternary

Comment: You are not returning anything in true case. This is as good as `return false` and loop will not end at first match. I'd suggest, `obj.Country === 'Austria' && (index = i); return index != -1`

Comment: @Rajesh - it works because the assignment is truthy if it's any number above `0`, and if it's `0`, then it's the first one, and can just return -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/jgwu6v1j/

Comment: I did not know this hack. Nice.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works for me and you saved my so much time. thanks once again

Answer (score 14):

You can use `array.findIndex` for this:

```js
var d = [{
  "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
  "Country": "Germany"
}, {
  "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
  "Country": "Sweden"
}, {
  "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
  "Country": "Mexico"
}, {
  "Name": "Ernst Handel",
  "Country": "Austria"
}];
var searchCountry = "Austria"
var index = d.findIndex(x=>x.Country === searchCountry)
console.log(index)
```

Note: [array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) is a part of ES6.

Answer (score 3):

```
Use findIndex method - 
   var index = $scope.records.findIndex(x=>x.Country==='Austria')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getIndexByCountryName(country)
    var found = $scope.records.find(function(item){return item.Country === country});
    return $scope.records.indexOf(found);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do which returns the countries and then finds the country.

```
$scope.records.map((item) => { return item.Country;}).indexOf('Austria')
```

The problem with the above code iterates once through each element to generate a map and then finds the index. You can use a simple for loop:

```
var index = (arr, k, v) => { 
   var i = -1;len = (arr || []).length;  
   for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
     if (arr[i][k] === v) 
       return i;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

I noticed a lot of findIndex solutions. Please note: FindIndex method has been added to the ECMAScript 6 specification and may not be available in all JavaScript implementations yet as per MDN.

You can use the polyfill for findIndex(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and use the findIndex solution that others suggested. If you do not want to use the polyfill you can use the map and indexOf that I put as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using a for - in loop as it is a JSON array, you can do this

```
for(i in records) {
if(records[i].country=="Austria") 
console.log("index is :"+ parseInt(i)); // print index
}
```

Comment: `records` is already a Javascript object. You do not need a `JSON.parse`. Also `typeof i` is `string` and not a number as is expected out of a index function.

Answer (score 0):

I have registered this method and it works like charm,

```
Array.prototype.getIndexByValue = function (name, value) {
        for (var i = 0, len=this.length; i <len; i++) {
            if (this[i][name]) {
                if (this[i][name] === value) {
                    return i
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    };

var d = [{
  "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
  "Country": "Germany"
}, {
  "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
  "Country": "Sweden"
}, {
  "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
  "Country": "Mexico"
}, {
  "Name": "Ernst Handel",
  "Country": "Austria"
}];


var index = d.getIndexByValue('Country','Austria');
console.log(index)//will print 3
```

Comment: You are leaking that variable `i` to window scope. Also if the value is not found return -1 instead of null to keep it consistent with the indexOf function.